# Hbase Java API connection error

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to connect from A java Application to Hbase like this:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    config.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");

    config.set("hbase.client.retries.number", Integer.toString(0));
    config.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", Integer.toString(60000));
    config.set("zookeeper.recovery.retry", Integer.toString(0));

    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
    TableName TABLE_NAME = TableName.valueOf("weblog");
    Table table = conn.getTable(TABLE_NAME);
    Result r = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("row1")));
    System.out.println(r);
```

I builded the App into a JAR but when running it on the cluster with :

```
hadoop jar hbaseConnect-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.packagename.hbaseConnect.HbaseConnect
```

i get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at com.DigiMerket.hbaseConnect.HbaseConnect.main(HbaseConnect.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I tried to add HBASE_CLASSPATH to HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop-env like this ​[post](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/10537/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-orgapachehadoophbaseh.html) suggests but I get the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by setting "HADOOP_CLASSPATH" as following and then in the same terminal run the hadoop/hbase jar:

```
 export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hbase/lib/hbase-client.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hbase/lib/hbase-common.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:.:"
```

Run the jar

```
hadoop  jar  hbaseConnect-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.packagename.hbaseConnect.HbaseConnect
```

Answer (score 0):

the log has prompt you run the jar need dependent other jar.
like hbase-client.jar

mkdir like libs and put you dependent jar into the dir of libs
and use this command:
java -Djava.ext.dirs=/xxx/xxx/xxx/lib -jar /xxx/xxx/you's jar

wish that can help u.